# perl regex: replace placeholder with variable content in template

Tags: regex, perl

i have some template string and some variables. 
for example something like the following:

```
my $template = " text <--Name--> some other text <--Age--> ...";
my $age = 15;
my $name = "heinz";
```

What is the correct Regex to replace the template placeholder strings with the corresponding perl variable?

I tried with

```
$template =~ s/<--(.*?)-->/eval('$' . lc($1))/sge;
```

but it does not work. The placeholder were replaced by an empty string.
I hope somebody has an idea.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use hash,

```
my $template = " text <--Name--> some other text <--Age--> ...";
my %hash = (age => 15, name => "heinz");

$template =~ s/<--(.*?)-->/$hash{"\L$1"}/g;
```

Comment: ok that seems to be a bit more elegant. but any way. how to do this with variables? i know i already saw it somewhere.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch https://eval.in/114388 but there are many reasons to avoid that => http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Comment: nice way to say that i am stupid :( but the tings are a little different. i do not create variables bases on input data. i just use internally defined variables that are also used for other internal purposes. But i agree with you: your approach is nicer and much more safe.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch this is in a way equivalent of register_globals in php  (bringing unnecessary security issues to your code)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is provided exactly by the [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aToolkit) module. However, your code works fine exactly as you have shown it

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $template = " text <--Name--> some other text <--Age--> ...";
my $age      = 15;
my $name     = "heinz";

$template =~ s/<--(.*?)-->/eval('$' . lc($1))/sge;

print $template, "\n";
```

**output**

```
 text heinz some other text 15 ...
```

But it is better to use a hash and keep all of the data in the same place. It also avoids using an evaluated substitution

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $template = " text <--Name--> some other text <--Age--> ...";

my %data = (
  age  => 15,
  name => 'heinz',
);

$template =~ s/<--(.*?)-->/$data{lc $1}/sg;

print $template, "\n";
```

Comment: ahhh - now as you told me that the example worked i got it. my code variables are all lower camel case (and the template vars upper camel case) and i simplified the names and strings a bit while pasting. of course i have to use lcfirst instead of lc

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, the proper way to do this is to use a hash.  However, if for whatever reason you are unable or unwilling to do that, then at minimum you need to make the left side of your regex more restrictive so that only variable names are caught and not random code.

[The Syntax of Variable Names](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#The-Syntax-of-Variable-Names) gives the explicit rules for perl variable names, but truth is that I suspect you don't really need package variables etc, so go ahead and make it more respective still.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $template = " text <--Name--> some other text <--Age--> ...";
my $age = 15;
my $name = "heinz";

$template =~ s/<--\s*([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\s*-->/'$' . lc($1)/sgee;

print $template;
```

Finally, it's possible to use more than one `e` modifier in a regex, so you don't actually need to  have an explicit eval inside the LHS of your regex.